# Hibernate criteria subclass attribute

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Invoice Class like this:

```
Invoice {
int id;
Set<Attachment> attachments;}
```

The Attachment class:

```
Attachment {
int id;
Status status;}
```

And, The Status class:

```
Status {
int id;
String desc;}
```

I want to build a method that given a status element, of an Attachment, return all related invoices.

This is my method:

```
    public List<Invoice> findbyCriteria(Invoice criteria, int init,
    int pageSize, String orderBy, String ascDesc) {


    Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Invoice.class).
    add(Example.create(criteria));
    if(criteria.getAttachment() !=null && criteria.getAttachment().size() > 0)
    c.createCriteria("attachments").add(Example.create((Set<Attachment>)criteria.getAttachments()));    

return c.list();
```

But this returns a ClassCastException during creation the Example:

```
Example.create((Set<Attachment>)criteria.getAttachments()));
```

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any relation mapping between `Invoice` and `Attachment` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
List<Invoice> invoices  = sess.createCriteria(Invoice.class)
                .add(what you need to filter)
                .createCriteria("attachments").add(what you need to filter)//like  Restrictions.like("name", "F%")
                .createCriteria("status").add(what you need to filter).list();
```